# Vulkan theaded application get error message on queue submissions under mutex

Tags: multithreading, vulkan

I have an application with Vulkan for rendering and glfw for windowing. If I start several threads, each with a different window, I get errors on threading and queue submission even though ALL vulkan calls are protected by a common mutex. The vulkan layer says:

> THREADING ERROR : object of type VkQueue is simultaneously used in thread 0x0 and thread 0x7fc365b99700

Here is the skeleton of the loop under which this happens in each thread:

```
while (!finished) {
    window.draw(...);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

The draw function skeleton looks like:

```
draw(Arg arg) {
    static std::mutex mtx;
    std::lock_guard lock{mtx};
    // .... drawing calls. Including
    device.acquireNextImageKHR(...);
    // Fill command bufers
    graphicsQueue.submit(...);
    presentQueue.presentKHR(presentInfo);
}
```

This is C++17 which slightly simplifies the syntax but is otherwise irrelevant.
Clearly everything is under a mutex. I also intercept the call to the debug message. When I do so, I see that one thread is waiting for glfw events, one is printing the vulkan layer message and the other two threads are trying to acquire the mutex for the lock_guard. 
I am at a loss as to what is going on or how to even figure out what is causing this.

I am running on linux, and it does not crash. However on Mac OS X, after a random amount of time, the code will crash in a queue submit call of MoltenVK and when the crash happens, I see a similar situation of the threads. That is to say no other thread is inside a Vulkan call.

I'd appreciate any ideas. My next move would be to move all queue submissions to a single thread, though that is not my favorite solution.

PS: I created a complete MCVE under the Vookoo framework. It is at https://github.com/FunMiles/Vookoo/tree/lock_guard_queues and is the example 00-parallelTriangles
To try it, do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/FunMiles/Vookoo.git
cd Vookoo
git checkout lock_guard_queues
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
examples/00-parallelTriangles
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212123/discussion-on-question-by-michel-vulkan-theaded-application-get-error-message-on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you call the draw is:

```
    window.draw(device, fw.graphicsQueue(), [&](){//some lambda});
```

The insides of `draw` is protected by mutex, but the `fw.graphicsQueue()` isn't.

`fw.graphicsQueue()` million abstraction layers below just calls `vkGetDeviceQueue`. I found executing `vkGetDeviceQueue` in parallel with `vkQueueSubmit` causes the validation error.

So there are few issues here:

- There is a bug in layers that causes multiple initialization of `VkQueue` state on `vkGetDeviceQueue`, which is the cause of the validation error

  - [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers#1751](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/pull/1751)
  - Thread id `0` is not a separate issue. As there are not any actual previous accesses, thread id is not recorded. The problem is the layers issue the error because the access count goes into negative because it is previously wrongly reset to `0`.
- Arguably there is some spec issue here. It is not immediatelly obvious from the text that `VkQueue` is not actually accessed in `vkGetDeviceQueue`, except the silent assumption that it is the sane thing to do.

  - [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs#1254](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1254)

Comment: This is indeed the issue! Thanks, @krOoze. You've been very patient with this and I appreciate it greatly! I was able to reach a correctly running code by retrieving the queue once and putting the locking where I wanted it, which is just around the queue submission(s). You are right that calling vkGetDeviceQueue for each draw does not sound like the ideal thing to do. And that was from the demos in the framework. So if I had not used the framework to ask for help, I'm not sure the issue would have been found in 2 days or less ;) Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Michel Yes, ideally the `fw.graphicsQueue()` should be cached and inlined function in the framework. Actual `vkGetDeviceQueue` could be called in the framework's equivalent of `createDevice` itself.

Comment: You are correct it should be. And it will be. I had developed my own framework for a scientific visualization app. In my framework, I had it retrieved once and cached. By doing some other work I discovered a list of libraries for Vulkan. I looked at them and saw that Vookoo had some of the features I had implemented and a few things further along while remaining a lightweight framework. So I decided to use it and contribute to it. I will contribute multi-window/multi-threading to it. Your help will allow Vookoo to improve and help many other people in the future, I hope.

Comment: as I am trying to really clean up the code and think about a user, the fact that calling vkGetDeviceQueue at the same time as using the queue is not thread safe is really an issue that is a Vulkan failing. It potentially makes it unsafe to call vkGetDeviceQueue to get a queue from a different family that actually maps to the same queue (similar/symmetric of your Vulkan-Docs question). I'm not sure if that's possible, but even if it isn't it means that any new threads that wants a queue to use has to go via a synchronized user-side system for any request combination (queue family/queue index).

Comment: @Michel Threading Layers currently do not assume `vkGetDeviceQueue` is any kind of access. The fix for your original issue was merged and will be part of the next SDK. The layers technically create its queue state when they first see a specific `VkQueue`, but that is internally synchronized. Normally, I would preassume queues form different qf give unique handles. Maybe worth if you make this a spec issue too.